# Filter, merge and sort lists of XML nodes

Tags: sorting, xslt, xpath, merge, xslt-2.0

I’m following instructions at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipcombxslt/ to merge my XML files. However, I’d like to do more tasks at once and cannot find a way to do it. Basically, I want to filter the input of merging (works already) and sort the output (need help).

**source.xml** defines the files containing nodes (in my case coding standard violations) to be merged. However, some of them contain violations of more rules than I want to keep in the output, so I specify `<rule>`’s to keep within some `<ruleset>`. When no rule is listed, *all* rules should be preserved.

```
<rulesets>
  <ruleset file="ruleset_M1.xml"/>
  <ruleset file="ruleset_all2.xml">
    <rule>X</rule>
    <rule>Y</rule>
  </ruleset>
</rulesets>
```

So here I want all rules from `ruleset_M1.xml` and rules `X` and `Y` from `ruleset_all2.xml`.

**ruleset_all2.xml** looks like this:

```
<violations>
  <violation file="Bra.h" line="1" rule="Z"
             msg="Function SPARC_Convert is not documented."/>
  <violation file="CpuArch.h" line="120" rule="X"
             msg="Parameters of member GetBe32 are not documented."/>
  <violation file="CpuArch.h" line="87" rule="X"
             msg="Parameters of member GetUi32 are not documented."/>
  <violation file="heapmgr.h" line="56" rule="Y"
             msg="The following parameter of HeapManager() is not documented: fill"/>
</violations>
```

and **ruleset_M1.xml** contains much more violations of much more rules which *all* should be kept.

I managed to do the filtering and merging using the following XSLT.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="/rulesets">
    <violations>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:sort select="@file"/><!-- help needed -->
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </violations>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ruleset">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="rule != ''">
        <xsl:variable name="current-rules" select="rule"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document(@file)/violations/violation[@rule = $current-rules]"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document(@file)/violations/violation"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now I want to sort the output by file name (`violation/@file`) but my `<xsl:sort>` does not work. The XPath `@file` matches the attribute of `<ruleset>`, not `<violation>`. I tried to replace it with `document(@file)/violations/violation/@file` and a few other options with no success. Can I somehow select an attribute in the output nodes of the second template instead of current source? Or should I change my XSL thoroughly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the merging works, I think the easiest is to merge first and then sort by changing

```
  <xsl:template match="/rulesets">
    <violations>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:sort select="@file"/><!-- help needed -->
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </violations>
  </xsl:template>
```

to

```
  <xsl:template match="/rulesets">
    <violations>
      <xsl:variable name="merged">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ruleset"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:perform-sort select="$merged/violation">
        <xsl:sort select="@file"/>
      </xsl:perform-sort>
    </violations>
  </xsl:template>
```

And anytime I see a match with xsl:choose, as in

```
  <xsl:template match="ruleset">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="rule != ''">
        <xsl:variable name="current-rules" select="rule"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document(@file)/violations/violation[@rule = $current-rules]"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy-of select="document(@file)/violations/violation"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

I think it should be restructured to

```
<xsl:template match="ruleset[rule]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="document(@file)/violations/violation[@rule = current()/rule]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ruleset[not(rule)]">
  <xsl:copy-of select="document(@file)/violations/violation"/>
</xsl:template>
```

As an alternative, I think you could use

```
  <xsl:template match="/rulesets">
    <violations>
      <xsl:perform-sort select="for $rs in ruleset[rule] return document($rs/@file)/violations/violation[@rule = $rs/rule], for $rs2 in ruleset[not(rule)] return document($rs2/@file)/violations/violation">
        <xsl:sort select="@file"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </violations>
  </xsl:template>
```

instead of

```
  <xsl:template match="/rulesets">
    <violations>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:sort select="@file"/><!-- help needed -->
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </violations>
```